# Anchor 28 to 29 ctx.remaining_accounts lifetime

Tags: anchor, lifetimes, remaining-accounts

In Anchor 28 we had a function that read remaining_accounts in as token accounts:

```
pub fn some_fun<'info>(
        &mut self, // the Context
        remaining_accounts: &[AccountInfo<'info>],
```

then in the body of the function we read a token account in:

```
            let acc_info = &remaining_accounts[i];
            let acc: Account<'info, TokenAccount> =
                Account::try_from(&acc_info)?;
```

Upgrading from Anchor 28 -> 29 flags this as a lifetime issue. It wants `Account::'info::try_from(&acc_info)?;`, but that requires significant upstream changes to the handler.

Even using remaining_accounts in the handler is painful with this change. For example if our handler was:

```
    pub fn handler<'info>(
        ctx: Context<'_, '_, '_, 'info, SomeCtx<'info>>,
    ) -> Result<()> {
            for account_info in ctx.remaining_accounts.iter() {
                let acc = Account::<TokenAccount>::try_from(account_info)?;
                // Do something with acc...
            }
```

throws a lifetime issue, and requires changing the Context to `ctx: Context<'_, '_, 'info, 'info, SomeCtx<'info>>,`

So my question is twofold: (1) Why the lifetime changes, and (2) If I don't care about the lifetimes at all (let's say I only want to read key and amount), what is the easiest workaround that doesn't require changing adding lifetimes for all instructions using remaining_accounts?

Comment: For reference, changing the function to take `remaining_accounts: &'info [AccountInfo<'info>],` as its argument, then the body to `let acc: Account<'info, TokenAccount> = Account::<'info>::try_from(&acc_info)?` and finally all Contexts to `ctx: Context<'_, '_, 'info, 'info, SomeCtx<'info>>,` does resolve the issue.